# Probability question: Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having a problem solving a probability question. At the moment I tried using the poisson distribution but I am getting the incorrect result. Can someone please help me solve the question.

The question reads: 
12. ℎ  ℎ     ℎ ℎ     0.5%.120  
   ,ℎ  ℎ  ℎ 4  ℎ  ℎ.
 ℎ

My solution is:
[image: qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq]

Comment: That's your exact solution or your approximation?  Why do you you use a mean of $.5$?

Comment: Also, my reading of the question would be "exactly four".  I can see someone saying it means "at least four", but I can't understand the reading "at most four".

Comment: @lulu I think it should  be "at least four". And I used the mean because it is part of the formula and thought it should be used

Comment: Well, you compute "at most four".  You do need a mean to use a Poisson process, but you aren't interpreting "mean" correctly.  I assume this is your approximation...have you got the exact value?

Comment: @lulu the exact value is 0.00287. However I do not know how to get the  exact value or approximate value.

Comment: Hint:  you never use the fact that you had $120$ students.  That information is clearly important!

Comment: Well, Poisson is an approximation here.  What kind of exact distribution is this?  Can you, say, compute the probability that no students are caught cheating?

Comment: For no students cheating I am getting 0.9355

Comment: No.  I have written out a solution....see if it makes sense.  For no students, the answer is $(1-.005)^{120}=0.547986285$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is poorly worded, in (at least) three ways.  First of all, we are given the probability that a student is caught cheating, but then asked about the number that cheat.  Anyone who has taught a class of $120$ knows that "cheating" and "getting caught" are not the same.  Secondly, it is not clear whether we are asked about "exactly four" cheaters or "at least four".  I will work the "exactly four" case.  To do the other, you need only compute "exactly  $0,1,2,3$ " and subtract from $1$.  Third,it is not made clear that we are meant to assume that each student is an independent event.  That's not realistic...in my experience, cheaters (especially those that get caught) work in groups.  But as we are told nothing about any dependence we are compelled to assume independence lest the problem be unsolvable.

Exact value:  This is a binomial process with probability $p=.005$.  As such the probability that we get exactly $k$ "successes" is $$p_k=\binom {120}k(.005)^k(1-.005)^{120-k}$$  This is easy to compute (with mechanical assistance) and we get $p_4=\fbox {0.002870399}$

Approximate value:  Poisson is a good idea here, but we have to get the mean right.  As we have $120$ students, we expect $.005\times 120=.6$ of them to be caught.  That's the mean we must use.  Thus the approximation is $$Poisson(4,.6)=\frac {.6^4e^{-.6}}{4!}=\fbox {0.002963583}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you just explain how you got p=.005 and how did you identify it's a binomial process?

Comment: You are given $p=.5\%$ and, as a decimal, that is $p=.005$.  As to the process, a Bernoulli process is a toss of a weighted coin, yes?  Well, each student is such a coin toss here.  Probability $p=.005$ that it comes up $H$, a cheater!    Probability $1-p$ that it comes up $T$, a non-cheater.  A binomial process is precisely an independent sample of a fixed Bernoulli process.  Note:  I am assuming that each event here is independent which is not realistic (in my experience, cheaters, especially those that get caught) work in groups.  Here you really have no choice but to assume independence.